# How to get the Unicode representation of an object

Tags: python, unicode, com

I have an instance and I want to get Unicode representation of it. The Unicode function Unicode () only accepts strings or buffers so I get an error if I pass the instance directly.

I have tried this:

```
document = self.grammar.application.ActiveDocument
style_map = [( unicode(s, 'utf-8'), s) for s in  document.Styles]
self.styles.set(dict(style_map))
```

I get this error:

```
style_map = [( unicode(s, 'utf-8'), s) for s in  document.Styles]
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found
```

I wonder how can I convert those instances to Unicode strings representations.
I didn't implement the objects. I'm accessing them through the COM interface.

Context:

This is a code for accessing the available formatting styles in a Word document using Python through a COM interface.
If I just try to convert the objects to ASCII strings I get the following error:

```
style_map = [( unicode(s), s) for s in  document.Styles]
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 207, in __str__ return str(self.__call__())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I would rather handle the issue on my code , instead of modifying some Win32 code.
As you can see I am using Python 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the instance into a representation with `repr()`:

```
document = self.grammar.application.ActiveDocument
style_map = [( unicode(repr(s), 'utf-8'), s) for s in document.Styles]
self.styles.set(dict(style_map))
```

Comment: Okay I don't get any errors, however I don't think that is working right. The generated list contains the names of the COM objects. So I have a list with this string repeated many times: u'<COMObject <unknown>>'. I should have a list with the names of the styles.:S

Comment: With `repr` you get a string representation of the object at hand:
`repr('a')` gives `"'a'"` and  `repr(sys)` gives `"<module 'sys' (built-in)>"`. It is for many cases the same as `str`. A notable exception is a string `str('a')` gives `'a'`. Hint: If you think an answer is useful, you can upvote it. ;)

Comment: Check with `dir(s)` what attributes such a style offers and use one of these, hopefully more descriptive attributes like `name` or `title` or such and convert this to unicode.

Comment: BTW, your questions was "How to get the Unicode representation of an object". That is exactly what my answer is doing. Wanting a telling name is a different question. ;)